# Inspection date conditional formatting symbology

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, arcade

I am trying to set symbology in ArcGIS Online based on Service Status, In or Out,  and Inspection Date, this will either be NULL or have a date.

- If a hydrant is IN or Out of service but has not been inspected (NULL
  Inspection Date) it will be gray
- If a hydrant is In service and inspected (NOT NULL Inspection Date)
  it will be red
- If a hydrant is Out of service and inspected (NOT NULL Inspection
  Date) it will be black

My current expression looks like this

```
if($feature.ServStat == 'In'&& $feature.InspDate=='NULL'){
return "gray"
}
if($feature.ServStat == 'In'&& $feature.InspDate=='NOT NULL'){
return "red"
}
if($feature.ServStat == 'Out'&& $feature.InspDate=='NULL'){
return "gray"
}
if($feature.ServStat == 'In'&& $feature.InspDate=='NOT NULL'){
return "black"
}
```

but is wrong.

Comment: Without testing, may be the issue is not to do with your expression but where and how you are actually running it? You do state if there is an error message nor do you explain how you are running this expression? Edit your question and add those details. Don't put them in the comments.

Comment: *How* is it wrong? In which case(es)? `"NULL"` and `"NOT NULL"` are not the values generally associated with null comparison.